# iptables rules for lxd container via ssh

Tags: ssh, lxc, lxd

Good day.
I use ubuntu 18 and want connect to my container via ssh. This is my container

```
cont    | RUNNING | 10.78.195.190 (eth0) | fd42:4be2:f986:212a:216:3eff:fee4:582 (eth0)  | PERSISTENT | 0         |
```

This is main ip 123.123.123.123

This is rule

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 23 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.78.195.190:22

/# iptables -L -n -t nat

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:23 to:10.78.195.190:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.78.195.0/24      !10.78.195.0/24       /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */

/# ifconfig
    enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.49  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::b62e:99ff:fec2:6c20  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b4:2e:99:c2:6c:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 7110  bytes 963405 (963.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3102  bytes 585809 (585.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 138  bytes 11996 (11.9 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 138  bytes 11996 (11.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lxdbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.78.195.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fd42:4be2:f986:212a::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::781c:22ff:fecf:a246  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:1d:37:ad:03:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 93  bytes 9937 (9.9 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 138  bytes 16179 (16.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    vethQLQTSD: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc26:27ff:fea1:806a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:26:27:a1:80:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 30  bytes 2946 (2.9 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 60  bytes 6593 (6.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    vethTE803A: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc1d:37ff:fead:347  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:1d:37:ad:03:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 63  bytes 8293 (8.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 81  bytes 9622 (9.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If i use ssh from my main system `ssh ubuntu@10.78.195.190`, i enter to container. But from another `ssh ubuntu@123.123.123.123 -p 23` not enter, connection timeout. What is my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `iptables`, I suggest to use [a LXD proxy device](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/instances#type-proxy).
Such a proxy device would forward incoming connections to the host at the specified IP address to the correct IP address at the container.

For your case, the command to create the proxy device is as follows.

```
lxc config device add mycontainer myport2222 proxy listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:2222 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:22
```

We created

1. a proxy device for container *mycontainer*
2. with the name *myport2222*
3. it is a **proxy** device
4. it listens on the host on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) on port *2222*, but you can configure to listen to a specific interface if you want.
5. it then connects to port 22 of the container on the loopback interface (no need to put the private IP address of the container, as LXD knows it already).

I notice that you use port *23*. This port is normally used for the Telnet protocol, and it is likely that some ISPs are blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was configuring a command in your incoming users .ssh/authorized_keys file that acts as a gateway into the LXD containers. This means you don't need any networking to get the jump server to work.
Quite a security feature when there you ssh into a Linux machine which only has a lo device.

I created a GitHub repository that details the setup and has the gateway script I use.

https://github.com/Dweller/lxd-ssh-gateway